# Java8-stream complex groupingBy

Tags: java-stream, groupingby

I want to do groupingBy and create a map that return me `<Integer, List<Long>>`
my model is as below

```
public class Partition {
    private String tableName;
    private int vendorKey;
    private int retailerKey;
    private int periodKey;
    private int amtKey;
    private int partitionId;
}
    
public class JobQueue {

    private List<Partition> partitions;
    private int transformId;
    private long processKey;
    private String configId;
   
}
```

I have written code using old java way and Want to rewritten below code in java-8 using groupingBy

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> processKeyMap = new HashMap<>();
        queues.forEach(q -> q.getPartitions().forEach(p -> {
                    int key = p.getPartitionId();
                    if (processKeyMap.containsKey(key)) {
                        List<Long> processKeys = processKeyMap.get(key);
                        processKeys.add(q.getProcessKey());
                        processKeyMap.put(key, processKeys);
                    } else {
                        processKeyMap.put(p.getPartitionId(), new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(q.getProcessKey())));
                    }
                }
        ));
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your current solution wastes time creating new Lists and then replacing them in the map.  You can do it like this.

- first if the map doesn't contain the `key (partitionId)`, then add it with an empty list.
- then continue to the next statement and get the list for that key (it must be there since you either just added it or it was there before) and add the `value (processKey)` to that retrieved list.

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> processKeyMap = new HashMap<>();
queues.forEach(q -> q.getPartitions().forEach(p -> {
    int key = p.getPartitionId();
    if (!processKeyMap.containsKey(key)) {
        processKeyMap.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    processKeyMap.get(key).add(q.getProcessKey());

}));
```

Using Java 8+ compute methods added to the Map interface, this does the same thing with a single statement. Although a `streams/groupingBy` solution is possible, the following is, imho, easier and a more straight forward solution.

- [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) - put the key and a value in the map if it is not there.  It then either returns the just added value or the one already associated with that key.  In both cases that is the list where the `processKey` is added.

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> processKeyMap = new HashMap<>();
queues.forEach(q -> q.getPartitions()
        .forEach(p -> processKeyMap
                .computeIfAbsent(p.getPartitionId(),
                        v -> new ArrayList<Long>())
                .add(q.getProcessKey())));
```

Streams solution using `groupingBy`.  They may be a better way to do this with streams.

- stream the `JobQueue` instances.
- then stream each JQ's `Partition` instances, packaging selected info in
  a `Map.entry(partitionId, processKey)` as an interim `key, value` pair
- then group them by the Entry key and map to the Entry value, prior to putting the `processKeys` in a list.

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> processKeyMap = queues.stream()
         .flatMap(q -> q.getPartitions().stream().map(
                 p -> Map.entry(p.getPartitionId(), q.getProcessKey())))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors
                 .mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```